# Uncaught ReferenceError: sizeFrame is not defined

Tags: html

Добрый вечер!

Google консоль показывает такую ошибку: **Uncaught ReferenceError: sizeFrame is not defined**

Вот код:

```
<iframe onload="sizeFrame();" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0" id="ftpdd" name="ftpdd" ></iframe>

function sizeFrame() {
  var F = document.getElementById("ftpdd");
  if (F.contentDocument) {
    F.height = F.contentDocument.documentElement.scrollHeight+30;
  } else {
    F.height = F.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+30;
  }
}

window.onload=sizeFrame;
```

Я так понимаю, гугл говорит о том, что **sizeFrame** не был найден, но почему? Подскажите пожалуйста, не могу разобраться.

Comment: потому что в данном случае определении функции должно быть раньше использования

Comment: @Grundy, блин, точно! Спасибо большое. А можешь еще подсказать по поводу этой ошибки? Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css(...).dialog is not a function

Comment: а что тут? вроде ясно написано, что нет такой функции _dial‌​og_ - либо плагин нужный не подключен, либо использование функции css как getter, а не setter, в случае getter (получение значения) возвращаемое значение не jQuery объект, поэтому закономерно у него нет функций из jQuery

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо, буду разбираться.

Comment: @Grundy оформите ответом Ваш комментарий.

Comment: @edem, Добавил ответ. Но мне кажется тут больше _опечатка_

Comment: @Grundy, а закрыл вопрос зачем?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае использования *inline* обработчиков, используемые функции должны быть объявлены *до* места использования в разметке.

Обычно их помещают в секцию *head*.